# How to "bless" a disc without access to OSX?

Tags: fedora, boot, osx

I have a MacBook Pro.  The original harddrive died and has been replaced.  I've installed Fedora20 on the new drive.

The new drive was never "blessed" and thus boot takes 30 seconds longer than it needs to.

**What's the easiest way to bless the disc without access to an OSX disc?**

Notes: 
1) I have the original OSX disc.  My Mac has an obscure fault that means OSX constantly reboots the machine while Linux doesn't.  (Any hints about fault finding gratefully received) also the install disc is at my sister's house.

2) I have very limited access to the Internet so downloading large ISOs is going to be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to non-OS X partitions, [`bless`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/bless/) only does two things:

1. Make sure the partition is marked as bootable. The Fedora installer should have already taken care of this. If so, `bless` will not do anything for you.
2. Adjust the Mac's [NVRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_memory) settings to make the chosen volume the default boot volume. Apple being Apple, the mechanism to do this is likely to be proprietary and obscure.

   Those obstacles are not sufficient to preclude a solution in themselves, but when you couple them with the fact that the only reason such software needs to exist is to allow a Mac to dual-boot, and all Macs come with a copy of Apple's `bless` utility, there isn't going to be a lot of incentive to create a third-party alternative.

I suggest that you go retrieve the OS X disc from your sister, boot it into the rescue mode, drop to a Terminal, and run `bless` from there.

If the hardware is truly in such a poor state that it can't even work long enough to get to a Terminal window on the boot CD, you're probably fooling yourself in believing that the hardware "works" under Linux in the first place. The minor inconvenience of having to manually choose the OS on boot is secondary to the risk you assume by continuing to trust that hardware.

Comment: Honestly - running Mac OSX causes frequent hard reboots.  Usi. The Install disc is hard because the machine reboots frequently throughout the process - and almost always when the graphical desktop is brought up.  Running memtest? No problem.  Installing and running Fedora (and minecraft and gstreamer) - no problem.  Going back to OSX after those tests - frequent reboots.  It's very frustrating.

Comment: I would guess that your GPU is faulty, then. Linux won't push it as hard as OS X will, in the typical case. OS X is *always* using the GPU, these days.